# Why does HAVING MAX() return a different value than SELECT MAX()?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `log` that contains, among others, a `DateTime` column called `TimeOfLog` and a foreign key `Logger_ID`.

What I was trying to do was get the newest entry per `Logger_ID`.

```
SELECT l.TimeOfLog AS TimeOfLog, l.Logger_ID AS Logger_ID 
FROM `log` `l` 
GROUP BY l.Logger_ID
HAVING MAX(l.TimeOfLog)
```

this however returns more or less a random `TimeOfLog` belonging to that `Logger_ID`. If I then run

```
SELECT MAX(l.TimeOfLog) AS TimeOfLog, l.Logger_ID AS Logger_ID 
FROM `log` `l` 
GROUP BY l.Logger_ID
```

I get the expected, newest, result. However, I'm pretty sure the `Logger_ID` is not the one belonging to that `TimeOfLog`.

Why is that/What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Turn on strict_mode in MySQL and you will see that your first query fails. If you group by something - all other columns should be aggregated in your select clause

Comment: *this however returns more or less a random TimeOfLog belonging to that Logger_ID* this is the expected behavior when you select a column not included in the group by clause.

Comment: @forpas I know it is, I just added that as a clarification as it is a requirement for a larger SQL query.

Comment: Why? It is logically wrong and if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled it is also syntactically wrong.

Comment: What is your question again? Apparently the log table contains ***many*** TimeOfLog  for a given Logger_ID... in which case MySQL can return ***any*** TimeOfLog value for a group. That should explain the "random" part of your question. This is a discouraged "feature" of MySQL and it is disabled by default since MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @forpas I don't understand what you are trying to say there.

Comment: Juergen is right. MAX(c.TimeOfLog) is not a condition, it will not work properly after HAVING

Comment: @SalmanA why the returned `TimeOfLog` value is different/why the first statement doesn't return the most recent `TimeOfLog`

Comment: I'm asking: why do you use a functionality that you know it produces *random* values?

Comment: @forpas well, for the first statement I didn't know that it wouldn't work. For the second one: I wanted to check that MAX is actually working correctly on a DateTime column, which it does.

Comment: @PierreSevrain ugh, crap. yeah, seeing it now. HAVING needs a boolean as a result. Obviously.

Comment: `MAX(l.TimeOfLog)` is correct in both queries. You don't use it correctly in the first query. `HAVING MAX(l.TimeOfLog)` does not mean what you thing it does. It should be `HAVING MAX(l.TimeOfLog) = <something>`

Comment: @forpas yeah, realized that just seconds before. Don't know why I didn't saw that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the maximum row, don't think `group by`; think filtering.  Here is one method:

```
select l.*
from log l
where l.timeoflog = (select max(t2.timeoflog)
                     from log l2
                     where l2.logger_id = l.logger_id
                    );
```

If you just want the maximum time, then aggregation is appropriate:

```
select logger_id, max(timeoflog)
from log l
group by logger_id;
```

You have the expression:

```
HAVING MAX(l.TimeOfLog)
```

This just checks that the maximum is not `0` or `NULL`.

Comment: That solves the question without pointing out that I'm an idiot for not connecting that HAVING needs a boolean expression while MAX(l.TimeOfLog) returns a DateTime. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstarding how `GROUP BY` AND `HAVING` works.

`GROUP BY` groups all rows that have same values in columns specified columns together into one group. If you select one column that is not mentioned in `GROUP BY` without using agregate function, you will randomly get one value from the grouped rows.

If you use agregate function like MAX() then the function is applied on all grouped rows and then result is selected.

`HAVING` is a filter similar to `WHERE` but while `WHERE` is applied before grouping the `HAVING` filter is applied after grouping.
 You can use aggregate functions there. The correct usage of having might be for example

```
SELECT column, 
FROM table
GROUP BY column
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This query would only select values of column that are present more than once.

In your example the MAX(c.TimeOfLog) will always be true as long as c.TimeOfLog is not empty for at least one row in group so it won't filter anything.